# Transformar Json em lista array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, libcurl

Preciso transformar um resultado em JSON, em arrays para que eu possa criar uma lista...

Veja meu código:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [

    // Produtos
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.minhaloja.com.br/api.php/produtos',


    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
]);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print($out);
```

RESULTADO ATUAL:

```
{  "product":{"columns":["product_id","model","sku","upc","ean","jan","isbn","mpn","location","quantity","stock_status_id","image","manufacturer_id","shipping","price","points","tax_class_id","date_available","weight","weight_class_id","length","width","height","length_class_id","subtract","minimum","sort_order","status","viewed","date_added","date_modified"],"records":[[65,"Colete deslize preto","","","","","","","",1,6,"catalog\/WhatsApp Image 2017-06-01 at 15.40.45 (2).jpeg",8,1,"219.0000",0,0,"2017-06-01","1.00000000",1,"34.00000000","24.00000000","32.00000000",1,1,1,1,1,233,"2017-06-01 20:03:40","2017-06-19 17:51:27"]]}}
```

Quero que fique tipo assim:

- **Produto Quantidade       Preço**

  - Fone de ouvido    1       100
  - Mascara        88        74

Comment: Se quiser mais detalhes na minha resposta, considere [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar o conteúdo da variável `$out`. ;)

Comment: @LipESprY eu editei a pergunta. Mas o que eu quero é imprimir legivelmente como se fosse o resultado em uma tabela! Pois utilizando o meu código ou o seu ainda fica ilegível para o usuário final.

Comment: Obrigado vou aguardar então! Abração!

Comment: @LipESprY, eaí amigo, sabe me dizer?

Comment: Resposta atualizada. Mas, cara, eu simplesmente "apliquei" o que havia respondido no seu JSON. Qual a sua dificuldade em fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*- transformar um resultado em JSON, em arrays*"

Basta *parsear* o retorno do cURL:

```
json_decode($out, true);
```

O segundo argumento `true` define que a função `json_decode` retorne como *array* associativo, ao invés de um objeto da classe `\stdClass`.

Ou seja:

```
<?php
$json = '{"chave1":"valor1", "chave2":"valor2"}';

$array_assoc = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($array_assoc);
/* Retorna:
 *    Array
 *    (
 *        [chave1] => valor1,
 *        [chave2] => valor2
 *    )
 ******************************************/
```

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

---

**@edit:**

> "*- Mas o que eu quero é imprimir legivelmente como se fosse o resultado em uma tabela! Pois utilizando o meu código ou o seu ainda fica ilegível para o usuário final.*"

Ora, depois de "decodificar" a *string* JSON, basta você exibir os valores. Você já tem a lista que queria:

```
<?php

$out = '{  "product":{"columns":["product_id","model","sku","upc","ean","jan","isbn","mpn","location","quantity","stock_status_id","image","manufacturer_id","shipping","price","points","tax_class_id","date_available","weight","weight_class_id","length","width","height","length_class_id","subtract","minimum","sort_order","status","viewed","date_added","date_modified"],"records":[[65,"Colete deslize preto","","","","","","","",1,6,"catalog\/WhatsApp Image 2017-06-01 at 15.40.45 (2).jpeg",8,1,"219.0000",0,0,"2017-06-01","1.00000000",1,"34.00000000","24.00000000","32.00000000",1,1,1,1,1,233,"2017-06-01 20:03:40","2017-06-19 17:51:27"]]}}';

$array_assoc = json_decode($out, true);

print_r($array_assoc);
/* Retorna:
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [columns] => Array
                (
                    [0] => product_id
                    [1] => model
                    [2] => sku
                    [3] => upc
                    [4] => ean
                    [5] => jan
                    [6] => isbn
                    [7] => mpn
                    [8] => location
                    [9] => quantity
                    [10] => stock_status_id
                    [11] => image
                    [12] => manufacturer_id
                    [13] => shipping
                    [14] => price
                    [15] => points
                    [16] => tax_class_id
                    [17] => date_available
                    [18] => weight
                    [19] => weight_class_id
                    [20] => length
                    [21] => width
                    [22] => height
                    [23] => length_class_id
                    [24] => subtract
                    [25] => minimum
                    [26] => sort_order
                    [27] => status
                    [28] => viewed
                    [29] => date_added
                    [30] => date_modified
                )

            [records] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 65
                            [1] => Colete deslize preto
                            [2] => 
                            [3] => 
                            [4] => 
                            [5] => 
                            [6] => 
                            [7] => 
                            [8] => 
                            [9] => 1
                            [10] => 6
                            [11] => catalog/WhatsApp Image 2017-06-01 at 15.40.45 (2).jpeg
                            [12] => 8
                            [13] => 1
                            [14] => 219.0000
                            [15] => 0
                            [16] => 0
                            [17] => 2017-06-01
                            [18] => 1.00000000
                            [19] => 1
                            [20] => 34.00000000
                            [21] => 24.00000000
                            [22] => 32.00000000
                            [23] => 1
                            [24] => 1
                            [25] => 1
                            [26] => 1
                            [27] => 1
                            [28] => 233
                            [29] => 2017-06-01 20:03:40
                            [30] => 2017-06-19 17:51:27
                        )

                )

        )
 */
```

Para retornar os valores específicos, basta você seguir o traço do valor desejado:

```
echo 'Produto: '.$array_assoc['product']['records'][0][1]; // Produto: Colete deslize preto
echo 'Quantidade: '.$array_assoc['product']['records'][0][9]; // Quantidade: 1
echo 'Preço: '.$array_assoc['product']['records'][0][14]; // Preço: 219.0000
```

Quando retornar mais de um produto, basta fazer um *loop* `foreach` na chave `['product']['records']`.

Comment: Amigo, fiz assim para retornar todos produtos:

$array_assoc = json_decode($out, true);

//print_r($array_assoc);

echo 'Produto: '.$array_assoc['product'];

foreach($array_assoc['product']['records'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
}

Mas retornou o erro:arning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/....

e Para mostrar 1 produto, fiz assim como falou: echo 'Produto: '.$array_assoc['product']['records'][0][1];

Mas não retornou nada!

Comment: @Alh que bom que está conseguindo! Hehe

Comment: Amigo, enviei a pergunta sem terminar de escrever pois o enter vai automatico, olha o que escrevi.. abraço!

Comment: @liPestpry se souber como ajudar...

Comment: @Alh consigo te ajudar sim. Mas essa pergunta já está acima do limite. Já é um novo problema. Tem algumas informações de contato no meu perfil. Só chamar de quiser algo mais dedicado.

Comment: Se você acha que esta acima do limite tudo bem. O que você me respondeu era o que eu sabia também, preciso solucionar de qualquer forma. Na minha pergunta já havia essa questão de imprimir em uma lista! Resolvo sozinho. abraço

Comment: @Alh não me entenda mal, cara. Eu não te neguei ajuda. Falei pra vc entrar em contato que eu iria te ajudar. Na pergunta vc quer saber como transformar um json em array. Depois ainda aplicamos minha resposta no seu json. Agora você tá com dificuldade em fazer um loop no array. Isso é questão à parte, no meu entender. Se achar melhor, pode criar um chat aqui tb. Vou te ajudar. Pode até ser via Teamviewer. Mas aqui é público pra trocar esse tipo de informação. Até!

Comment: Deu certo amigo! Acabei dando um nome para exemplo de uma coluna aqui, e depois não substitui pois o nome era quase igual. Agora deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Alh Disponha, colega! ✌